# Data collection on web site with web proxy using requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to collect data from a website, but the internet I'm using crashes some websites and a pop-up appears to enter the login and password for the proxy. This is the code I tried:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPProxyAuth

proxy_string = 'http://user:password@10.31.220.23:3218'

s = requests.Session()
s.proxies = {"http": proxy_string , "https": proxy_string}
s.auth = HTTPProxyAuth('user','password')


r = s.get('https://www.google.com/',
                    proxies={"http": proxy_string, "https": proxy_string})
print(r.text)
```

it gives me this error message:

```
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x02C07628>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] Uma tentativa de conexão falhou porque o componente conectado não respondeu\r\ncorretamente após um período de tempo ou a conexão estabelecida falhou\r\nporque o host conectado não respondeu')))
```

I tried starting sessions with a proxy but it didn't work

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAm9h.png)

Comment: Just a guess, but what happens if you set `proxy_string = 'http://10.31.220.23:3218'` without the `user:password`?

Comment: Also what happens if you `ping 10.31.220.23`? Does that connect?

Comment: I tried but it gave an error again, I put in the post what appears when I try to enter a site that needs access.  @Ben

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm out of ideas. Can you contact whoever owns the proxy infrastructure on your network and ask them?